# JQuery unable to use find method using a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been trying to figure out why find method selector is not detecting the 'city' variable. Here's the code.

html

```
<div id="cities">
  <div class="Denver"></div>
  <div class="Seattle"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery - The data I get returned from getCity.php is a string "Denver, Seattle".

```
$.post("getCity.php", function(data){
    var cityArr= data.split(",");
        $.each(cityArr, function(i, city){
            $('#cities').find('.'+city).html(city);
        });

});
```

This piece of code does not work. Now if i change `find('.'+city)` to `find('.Denver')` or `find('.Seattle')` then it works.. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what's in the `data` ?

Comment: Is `data` in lowercase? Is there a space in array item returned by `.split(",")`?

Comment: try `$('#cities').find('.'+city.trim()).html(city);`

Comment: why do you expect `.find(city)` should work? `city` isn't element but you're targeting a class so, you did `.find('.'+city)` which works fine. Nothing I can see wrong.

Comment: Working fine if your data is in this format https://jsfiddle.net/y7e37yas/ .

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Where is `.find(city)` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 OP updated the question just now.

Comment: can you provide data from php?

Comment: .trim() does the job. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is whitespace after `,` in your string so use **[`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)** or **[`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)**

```
$('#cities').find('.' + city.trim()).html(city);
```

or

```
$('#cities').find('.' + $.trim(city)).html(city);
```

---

Otherwise you need to split string with comma with space.

```
var cityArr= data.split(/\s*,\s*/);
```